# How to implement an interface for an imported class

Tags: c#, itext

I am trying to order a list of objects by height. The list contains both `TextChunk` and `Rectangle` types, so it would be really convenient to just make an interface they both conform to which contains their maximum height then sort by that. Problem is, I don't know how to make a class I imported conform to an interface. New to C#, so pardon for the basic question.

Comment: In short, you can't make a class you don't have control over implement an interface you do. You'd have to create another class you do have control over implement the interface, and wraps the imported class.

Comment: As @HereticMonkey wrote - use [adapter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add interfaces to classes that already exist.

What you can do is write a wrapper class with implicit conversion to make your life easier.

```
class ShapeWithHeight
{
    private ShapeWithHeight(object shape, int height)
    {
        this.Shape = shape;
        this.Height = height;
    }
    public int Height { get; }
    public object Shape { get; }

    static public implicit operator ShapeWithHeight(TextChunk chunk) => new ShapeWithHeight(chunk, chunk.Height);
    static public implicit operator ShapeWithHeight(Rectangle rectangle) => new ShapeWithHeight(rectangle, rectangle.Height);
}
```

Now you can do this:

```
var list = new List<ShapeWithHeight>
{
    new TextChunk { Height = 110 },
    new TextChunk { Height = 120 },
    new TextChunk { Height = 190 },
    new Rectangle { Height = 160 },
    new Rectangle { Height = 130 },
    new Rectangle { Height = 140 }
};

var sortedList = list.OrderBy(x => x.Height).ToList();
foreach (var o in sortedList)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Height: {0} Type: {1}", o.Height, o.Shape.GetType().Name);
}
```

Output:

```
Height: 110 Type: TextChunk
Height: 120 Type: TextChunk
Height: 130 Type: Rectangle
Height: 140 Type: Rectangle
Height: 160 Type: Rectangle
Height: 190 Type: TextChunk
```